# Python - TKinter - Destroying widgets not lowering frame height

Tags: python, tkinter, height, frame

I am having and issue where I have a frame in a game that displays the current progress of the game (let's call this frame; "results").

If the player chooses to start a new game all the widgets inside results get destroyed and the frame is forgotten to hide it until it is used again.

Now the issue I am having is; When results gets called back it is in-between two other frames. However, it has remained the size it was in the previous game when it has contained all the widgets, before the widgets were destroyed. The widgets are not shown in the frame but it's still the size it was when the widgets were there.

As soon as a new widget is placed in results the size is corrected but I can't figure out how to make the `height = 0`. I have tried `results.config(height=0)` but that hasn't worked.

Does anyone know how to "reset" the size of the frame to 0?

Sorry for the proverbial "wall-of-text" but I couldn't find a way to provide the code in a compact way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If I completely understand what you want, then this illustration is correct:

*The blue is the **results** frame*

[image]

*The **results** removed, everything else resized:*

[image]

And the corresponding code for this is something like:

```
import tkinter

RESULTS_WIDTH = 128

root = tkinter.Tk()

left_frame = tkinter.Frame(root, height=64, bg='#cc3399')
right_frame = tkinter.Frame(root, height=64, bg='#99cc33')

def rem_results(event):
    # Remove widget
    results.destroy()
    # Resize other widthets
    left_frame.config(width=128 + RESULTS_WIDTH/2)
    right_frame.config(width=128 + RESULTS_WIDTH/2)
    # Reposition other widgets
    left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    right_frame.grid(row=0, column=1)

def add_results(event):
    # Create results widget
    global results
    results = tkinter.Frame(root, width=RESULTS_WIDTH, height=64, bg='#3399cc')
    results.grid(row=0, column=1)
    # Resize other widgets
    left_frame.config(width=128)
    right_frame.config(width=128)
    # Reposition other widgets
    left_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
    right_frame.grid(row=0, column=2)

# Initialize results
add_results(None)

# Bind actions to <- and -> buttons
root.bind( '<Left>', rem_results )
root.bind( '<Right>', add_results )

#$ Enter eventloop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: No, I don't destory the result's frame at any point. I use results.pack_forget() to remove it to save having to create the frame every time. It also avoids having to use "global" which is not a good thing to use afaik so I've been avoiding it.

Comment: I don't recommend you to use global, I only did here, because on SO in tkinter questions we don't use classes to help solving a problem (for easier understanding), only if the OP's provide a code that is using OO. But since you did not posted anything from your code, I had to write it from scratch. Next time you should create a simplified version of your code and paste it along with your question, and you will have a better answer.